# how to enable MACRO feature in the Dokuwiki <code> block

Tags: macros, dokuwiki

I am using the [textinsert](https://www.dokuwiki.org/plugin%3atextinsert) plugin to perform macro functionality in Dokuwiki.

It works for most of the occasion but failed in the `<code>` block. 
The macro syntax #@MACRO_HTML@# output as-is and this behavior is not favorable.

```
#@MACRO_HTML@#
```

The idea behavior should be that the #@MACRO_HTML@# is replaced with text like "this is the favorable text" in the wiki page.

```
this is the macro text
```

Please show me a way to enable macro functionality within the `<code>` block for Dokuwiki.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at [the code](https://github.com/splitbrain/dokuwiki/blob/5fd5f78803a876c5808be4d3ba63cc5b85754f25/inc/parser/parser.php#L35) of Dokuwiki, we see that the <code> mode doesn't accept any other mode.

Hence it's not possible to use another plugin inside a <code> block.